# using 'appendTo()' in a div inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was searching for this one for a couple of hours now but I couldn't find the exact same problem as mine:

I have the following code in my html:

```
<div id="list" style="display:none;">
     <div id="insideList">
      <!-- Some picture will go here -->
     </div>
</div>
```

when I'm wrote in my JavaScript file:

```
$("<img src=\"images/somePicture.jpg\">").appendTo("#list");
```

it worked fine, however when I tried writing:

```
$("<img src=\"images/somePicture.jpg\">").appendTo("#insideList");
```

It showed nothing on the page. What am I missing here?

**Edit: I'm calling `$("#list").show();` eventually...**

Comment: `style="display:none;"` hides the element. What do you expect?

Comment: Works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8W2gt/) without the `display:none`.

Comment: "It showed nothing on the page." Expected result with the display none ....

And it work when i call $('#list').show();

Comment: Please notice my edit as I do call `$("#list").show();` eventually. In addition, as I mentioned before, `appendTo("#list");` Does show the image!

Comment: @user, do you have more than element with id `insideList` in your document?

Comment: remove the `style="display:none;"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are gonna append to inside list, then try to set display:none for insideList and call insideList.show() instead of list.show();